# Start Function After Share Intent Android

Tags: android, onactivityresult, android-sharing

I am using the share dialog to share a text in twitter with the code below.

```
postTweetAfterIntentVar = 1;

Intent tweetIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
tweetIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
tweetIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "tweet text here");
tweetIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(tweetIntent, "Share this via"));
```

And I want to start a function after the share operation is finished. I use the code below, but nothing happends after the share operation with the intent is finished. Am I doing anything wrong? Any help would be great.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    if (postTweetAfterIntentVar == 1) {

        postTweetAfterIntentVar = 0;

            postTweetFunc();


    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onActivityResult()` will not be invoked if you start your activity using `startActivity()`.

`onActivityResult()` gets invoked once you start any activity using `startActivityFoResult()` and not `startActivity()`. 
So, when you start activity using `startActivityFoResult()` the called activity sets the result using `setResult()` and then you get that result in `onActivityResult()`.

Comment: Hello Shadab, so replacing startActivity() with startActivityForResult() will be enought?

Comment: Yes and in `onActivityResult()` you can check  for the specific `requestCode`.